# Can't see Developer mode in Magento 2.2.9 after enabling it

Tags: magento2, ultimo

When I enable Developer mode in Magento, I don't see it in the Configuration Settings:
[image]

I used command

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

I'm using Magento 2.2.9 and Ultimo Theme version 2

Comment: Please check env.php and ensure that Mage_Mode  is developer

Comment: I just checked it and it says "developer" there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly I've done, but I can see it now. I guess I was using the right command `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`, but I had to clean the cache.